# gamma distribution probability

Tags: gamma-function, gamma-distribution

Am I doing this gamma distribution correctly?

Calculate $P(Y>4)$ while $Y\sim \Gamma(a,b) \text{ with } a = 2, b =3$

$P(Y > 4) = 1 - P(Y \leq 4)$

with pdf $f(y)$ given

$$f(y) = \frac{1}{(b^a\Gamma(a))}*y^{a-1}*\exp(\frac{-y}{b})=\frac{1}{9}y\exp(\frac{-y}{3})
$$
therefore we get
$$
P(Y>4)=1 - P(Y \leq 4)= 1 - \int_{0}^{4}\frac{1}{9}y\exp(\frac{-y}{3})dy\approx0.615
$$

Comment: do you how to use LaTex by the way? the above editor supports it and the result looks much nicer and easier accessible

Comment: @user190080 I'm sorry I don't.

Comment: alright, I edited your post - with a right click on the body you can choose "Show Math as " and then TeX commands to have a look how I did it

Answer (score 0):

yes your result is correct, since

$$
P(Y>4)=1-P(Y\leq 4)=1- F_{gamma}(4,2,3)\approx 0.615 \text{ with }\Gamma(2)=1
$$
I just want to point out that there are different ways of defining the parameter $a,b$ of the [corresponding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) Gamma distribution. So just make sure you took the right pdf and you're fine.

bests